# Node EventEmitter event.on() fires twice after only a single emit issued

Tags: javascript, node.js, vscode-extensions, eventemitter

I have a VSCode extension (no browser involved) where I need to manage the allocations of session.
I have this code snippet in my SessionManager class:

```
private event = new EventEmitter();
private sessionArray = [];
public async getSession(sessionName: string) {
    let index: number;
    index = this.sessionArray.findIndex((a) => a.sessionName === sessionName && a.inUse === false);
    if (index === -1) {
      // no session available
      await new Promise((resolve) => this.event.on("available", resolve));
      index = this.sessionArray.findIndex((a) => a.sessionName === sessionName && a.inUse === false);
    }
    this.sessionArray[index].inUse = true;
    return { session: this.sessionArray[index], id: index };
  }
  /**
   * set the session status back to available and emit the event
   */
  public async freeSession(id: number) {
    this.sessionArray[id].inUse = false;
    this.event.emit("available");
    return;
  }
```

My session array has a single entry
When I step through the code with debugger first time through I fnd the emtpy slot in sessionArray, i use that slot and set to inUse.
A second request comes in for a session, doesn't find one that is available so triggers the await on the promise waiting for the emit event to fire.
A third request comes in and does the same thing and queues a Promise on the emit event
Finally the 1st request completes and issues the freeSession which sets the slot to available and emits the event. Immediately the event triggers and resolves the promise and triggers finding the now available slot - all good so far.

But...immedately, the event.on triggers again and causes an error as there is no available slot and so index returns with a -1

I am missing something obvious but I cannot see why the event triggers twice in rapid succession after only a single emit was issued.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `this.event` is the same event all the time. So triggering this event will fire all listeners waiting for the event at that moment.

Also by the way you never remove the old listener (or set it to `once`) so you have a memory leak and also uselessly call `resolve` on already-resolved promises.

Comment: not sure why you say the Promise is useless,  as I need to wait till the event is triggered. The await on the promise accomplishes that. 

Changing the event. on to event.once doesn't make any difference in that only one emit occurs but the event still triggers  twice.

Comment: No, I didn't say the promise itself was useless, I said that because you don't remove the listener after it fired and neither set it to fire only once, previous listeners will fire again on future events even though their promises were already resolved, repeatedly calling `resolve` on an already-resolved promise, also preventing their closures from being released, thus creating a memory leak.

Comment: But it's the same event all the time, isn't it? You trigger the same event multiple times, once when the first thing becomes available, once when the second becomes available, etc. At no point I see you creating a new, separate event emitter. You are right there is only one emit on the first occurrence but at that point there are already two listeners attached, causing both to trigger.

Comment: It actually sounds like you want a sort of "queue" (where a single session is given to the longest-waiting requester), not an event emitter (where all the listeners trigger at once). In that case you could simply queue the `resolve` functions in an array and when a session becomes available, you unshift the earliest "waiter" from the array and call it. Similarly you could push sessions that become available while nobody is waiting for them into a separate array and first use those in case a new session is requested and only if there are none then you would queue a `resolve` function instead.

Comment: Sorry, when I wrote "unshift" I meant "shift". Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/e7fvwacr/

Comment: I took your sample and modified it to work within Node.js and I have this working now. The trick that had me stuck was this:
`if (waiter) {
    waiter(burger) 
`
I would never have fathomed that out.